# Getting back to Dreamweaver CS4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dreamweaver

My problem is that I want to assign a keyboardshortcut for Dreamweaver CS4 and I have it like this: "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS4\Dreamweaver.exe" Thats ok so far.

But when I press the key it doesn't place itself infront of everything else like Outlook and Visual Studio does for example, instead it blinks in the taskbar, and I have to click there anyway to get back to Dreamweaver.

Is there any switch or something I can assign for Dreamweaver to get back AND have it "popup?"

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Solution

Try the following, it may solve the problem.

Right click the shortcut, and click on Properties.  In the `Shortcut` tab, click the drop-down option beside `Run:`, and select `Maximized.

Hit apply, close the box, run 'er, and see what happens.

There's two other things you can try.

### More Advanced Solution

The first is a simple VBScript to launch an application.  What you need for this is the window title of Dreamweaver when it first launches.  The code is as follows:

```
set oshl = createobject("Wscript.Shell")
oshl.run "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS4\Dreamweaver.exe", 10, false
do
    'search for name of window to activate
    retval = oshl.AppActivate("**DREAMWEAVER WINDOW TITLE GOES HERE**")
    if retval then exit do
    wscript.sleep 100
    count = count + 1
loop until count = 50 'loop for 5 seconds - change this if you need
```

Copy & paste that into Notepad, replace `**DREAMWEAVER WINDOW TITLE GOES HERE**` with the window title of Dreamweaver, save it as "launchDreamweaver.vbs", and launch that instead of the Dreamweaver executable.

### Even More Advanced Solution

If that doesn't work, if you're a tad ambitious, you can write a program and invoke the BringWindowToTop function in user32.dll (see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673(VS.85).aspx) for method details).  Then you could write a simple C#/C++/VB program to launch the program, and then set the Z-order.

I know that this may not be the most preferred method, but I don't believe you can invoke `user32.dll` using VBScript...

Comment: Allright, seems like some great stuff to dig into, but after a quick readthrough, how do I get the windowtitle of DreamWeaver?

Thanks!
/Christer

Comment: Just look at the window title in the taskbar or the actual window itself (or if you go to the Task Manager, it will be the entry in the Task column).